# Sylius Database Credentials Not Updating

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

I'm new to Sylius, and am configuring a site for the first time on MAMP Pro. I've installed Sylius via Composer, but realized that the database credentials I provided during install were not correct. After this, I went into **app/config/parameters.yml** as per the documentation, and updated the following credentials:

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: localhost
database_port: null
database_name: mydb
database_user: root
database_password: root
```

What's happening is every time I try to access the site, it throws a 500 error. Upon checking my log, each time I try to access it, I get an error about access being denied to the DB:

```
[15-Aug-2016 13:49:34 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
```

The strange thing is the error log also shows this:

```
vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php(41): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', 'secret', Array)
```

These are the old credentials (notice the password 'secret' instead of 'root', and the host '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'. It appears that despite updating my **parameters.yml** with the correct credentials, Sylius won't stop trying to connect with the original credentials I used during setup. Is there another file that this could be stored in that's not mentioned in the documentation? Could it be caching the old credentials, and in need of some clearing? I'm at a loss for what's happening here.

*EDIT*:

I've also tried updating **app/config/parameters.yml.dist** with the proper credentials, to no effect.

*EDIT 2*:

I've done an entire search of the project for the name of my old database, and have updated each instance to the new database name. There are no files that reference the old DB name. Then I try and run:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug
```

and it throws errors:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
```

SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  database "old_database_name" does not exist

despite old_database_name not being referenced in any file. Then if I do a search for old_database_name AFTER running the cache clear, it overwrites my new database name in app/cache/de_/ap_DevProjectContainer.php with the old name again, every time. I can't even figure out where it's getting the old database name from, after I overwrite every instance of it. What's happening here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Sylius configuration uses a different database for production and development. In your case, this would be `sylius` from prod and for the dev environment `_dev` is appended to the datbase name. This is expected behavior and not a bug.

You can find the configuration at the end of `app/config/config_dev.yml`. If you remove the following lines, both environments use the same database.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname: %sylius.database.name%_dev
```

https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/2362

Answer (score 0):

In this case, old_database_name was the same as my new database name, only it contained the suffix '_dev'. I've now realized that this is because I'm in the dev environment. There doesn't seem to be any easy way I've found to remove this suffix, so I'm just going to roll with it. Would still like an answer on how to remove this, but for now I've answered my own question.